# Retaining control after telling Preview to close a window

Tags: ruby, applescript

I have hundreds of images in a directory structure, and sometimes I want to look at them one by one in order to find the one I'm thinking of.

I'd like to bring each one up, and then if it's not the one I want, close it and look at the next one, with either a single mouse click or  a one-letter command in a terminal window.  Is it possible to open a file and retain control after doing an applescript tell to Preview to close the frontmost window.  When I try this,  Preview stays active, my script pauses, and I need to cmd-tab back to the iTerm window to have it continue. I've tried setting a timeout in applescript before I do the 'tell' to Preview, but that didn't work.   Is there a way around this?  Here's my current ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'find'

def osascript(script)
  system 'osascript', *script.split(/\n/).map { |line| ['-e', line] }.flatten
end

file_paths = []

Find.find('.') do |path|
  file_paths << path if path =~ /.*\.png$/
end

file_paths.each do |f|

  system "open '#{f}'"

  decision = gets.chomp

  if decision.eql? "s" then
    exit
  end

  osascript <<-END
  tell application "Preview" 
  close window 1 
  end tell
  END

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not just using standard Finder feature? Open the folder with the Finder, select the 1st file and type space bar to have a quick view. then just use up and down arrow keys to display next/previous images from that folder. Quicker and built-in.

An other way is to select, in the Finder window, a view per thumbnail. You can adjust the  size at bottom right of the window. Images are smaller, but you can see more of them at same time on your screen.

Comment: Thanks!   I had no idea I could do this. ... "It's all easy when you know how".  This is exactly what I wanted.